# Show there are $\aleph_0$ many 0-definable sets under a countable language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite L structure, where $L$ is countable language. I want to show that there are $\aleph_0$ many 0-definable sets in $\mathcal{M}$.

Attempt:

Proceed by induction on the formula $\phi$:

Define $\mathcal{D}= \{ A \subseteq M^n : \mathcal{M} \models \phi(a),  \forall a \in A\}$

Base case :

$\phi$ is an atomic formula.

Suppose $\phi$ is $(t_2=t_2)$ for some $L$-terms $t_1(x), t_2(x)$.

Then $\mathcal{M} \models \phi(a)$ iff $t_1^{\mathcal{M}}(a)=t_2^{\mathcal{M}}(a)$ for $a=(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in M^n$.

Suppose $t_1$ is the coordinate projection.

Then $t_1^{\mathcal{M}}(a)=a_i=t_2^{\mathcal{M}}(a)$ for $i=1, \cdots, n$.

So $A=\{$ a countable set in $M^n \}$.

$\mathcal{D}= \{$ the set of all countable sets $\}$...

But this is not what we wanted to show, since we want to show $|\mathcal{D}|= \aleph_0$.

Suppose $t_1$ is a constant symbol. Then since $L$ is countable by assumption, we have that $|\mathcal{D}|$ is countable.

But in the case of having finitely many constants symbols, we could also have $\mathcal{D}=$ finite..

So I'm not sure what I did wrong here.

Similarly, we also have the case $t_1$ is a function symbol, which we could also get $\mathcal{D}=$ finite.

And for the atomic formula base case, we also have that $\phi$ being a m-ary relation symbol, which I have the same problems.

Could someone please let me know what I did wrong, and how should I fix the proof?

Any ideas or hints will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, there's an obvious mistake in how you started the proof. You say you're going to do induction on "the formula". What formula? What is the statement you're trying to prove by induction? The goal is to count the number of definable sets - this is not a statement about a particular formula, it's a statement about the collection of *all* formulas.

Comment: I want to show that for all formulas $\phi$, we have $|\mathcal{D}|=\aleph_0$. Can't I just start from Atomic formulas, and expand it to all formulas? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood the question.  For a fixed formula $\phi$, showing that $\vert\mathcal{D}\vert = \aleph_0$ shows that $\phi$ defines a countable set.  That's quite different from showing that there are countably many definable sets.  (The question is "how many definable sets are there?", not "how big is each definable set?")

Comment: I see! Thanks so much! My original intention was to define $\mathcal{D}$ as the set of all 0-definable sets, hence we can show $|\mathbb{D}|= \aleph_0$. But now I know that I've defined $\mathcal{D}$ incorrectly, I'm not sure how I should represent the set of all 0-definable sets. Any hints or ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you may want to think of a systematic way of listing or grouping up all possible formulas without parameters up to logical equivalence. For example, up to logical equivalence, do you know how many formulas without parameters and with one free variable are there? What about formulas without parameters and with two free variables?

Comment: For example, if we only have 1 free variable $x$. Then we could have $x=c$, where $c$ is a constant symbol, which is countable?  Sorry, I'm still confused about how to produce the formulas without parameters up to logical equivalence. Could you give an example?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, is the question equivalent to showing that the set of all $L$- formulas have size $\aleph_0$? Thanks!